# how to check int and boolean optional parameter in Spring Mvc framework in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc framework and trying to develop a REST Api.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = StaticUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
public @ResponseBody String transliterateSimpleJSON(@RequestBody String inStringJson, @RequestParam(value = "target_lang", required = true) String tLang, @RequestParam(value = "check", required = false) boolean check,
        @RequestParam(value = "source_lang", required = false) String srcLang, @RequestParam(value = "domain") int domain, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale,
        Model model) {
//My code goes here
return "somthing";
}
```

Now as you can see srcLang,check and domain are optional parameter.for srcLang I am using the following code :

```
if (srcLang == null || srcLang.isEmpty()) {
                srcLang = tLang;
            }
```

But for the parameters like check (which is Boolean) and domain (which is int),I want to set some default value if these are not given in the URL.I want to set check=true and and domain=3.But I have not been able to do that as I did for String srcLang as I don't know how to check int and Boolean value Url parameters inside Controller.

Comment: Why don't you make use of defaultValue of Spring. If you want to handle in code then accept them using their wrapper classes and provide null checks similar to what you did for srcLang.

Comment: null check can not be done for int and boolean like we do  for String.That is what  I want to know how check for null in case of int and boolean values.

Comment: That's right. That's why I asked to use Wrapper classes for accepting theses values.
Like Integer and Boolean instead of int and boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `RequestParam` annotation. It has an attribute called `defaultValue` (type `String`) which can be used in the case an attribute is not there, like this:

```
@RequestParam(value="domain", required=false, defaultValue="10") int domain)
```

Comment: if required=true,then does it make any sense to provide default value?Can I write it like : @RequestParam(value="domain", required=false, defaultValue=10) int domain)

Comment: You're right, that was a copy and paste error; it doesn't make sense to a have a defaultValue in that case. I updated my answer.